# how to detect an element on web page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a chrome extension that would let me check if some elements are present on the page opened. I want this extension to run every time I open a new page and showing me a popup message if the element is on the page.
I've got this code in tampermonkey, though it does'`t seem to work.

```
(function() {
    var training = document.getElementsByName("test_id")
    if (training[0]) {
      alert("This page is tested");
    }   
})();
```

Comment: Maybe you want to wait for the [DOM do be ready](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)? you can't run your js before the html

Comment: Are you sure there is an element with a `name='test_id'` attribute in your DOM at load time?

Comment: The "name" in your `.getElementsByName()` has `_id` in it. Are you sure you want `.getElementsByName()`?

Comment: May i recommend [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)? Thinks this css selector is easier.

Comment: The element is hidden in a fragment, see the last line ``` <script type="text/javascript">!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod? n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n; n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0; t.src=v;s=b const $ws_params ={"test_id":0, "uni_mode":0};</script>```

Comment: The code in your comment has two issues; but regardless, even if it didn't it would not inject an element with a name attribute set to test_id. Are you just trying to find the substring in the whole document source?

Comment: If I inspect page and type in a search (ctr+f) test_id it shows me this element. Not all pages have this element. So I would like my extension to detect those pages where this element shows up

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```js
 function check(){
          var training=document.getElementById("test_id").value;        
          if(traing==0){
          alert("test complete");
           return false;
          }
        }
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->



    <input type="number" id='test_id' name='test_id'>
```

Comment: Hi! It doesn`t seem to work for me:/ I tried javascript injector and run javascript extensions on chrome. though there were no results

Comment: @Neon, In your Input element set id="test_id" and then in javascript call by document.getElementById("test_id").value;

Comment: I might be dumb, but still nothing, my brains burn, it seems so simple and so impossible at the same time...

Answer (score 0):

```
      var element = document.getElementsByName("test_id")
      if(element.length){
        alert("found")
      }else{
        alert("not found")
      }
```